# How to style orange flash in website when loading image

Tags: css

At http://communitychessclub.com/ the chessboard diagrams have an annoying orange flash for 1/2 second before the image loads.

How can I css style this to make the background some other color than orange?

The relevant code that produces the diagram:

```
<div class='hide-for-small-only left set_pic' style = 'clear: left; overflow: auto; margin-top:0.5rem;'>
<a data-tooltip class="has-tip" title = ". Harold Stenzel - . Igor Nikolayev (FM)" href = "basic.php?game=5402">
<img class="box lazyload" height="256" width="256; background:beige; " alt="diagram"  src="images/x.gif" 
data-src= "./ChessImager/diagram.php?fen=r1bq1rk1/ppp3pp/8/3p4/1Q1Pn3/2N2N2/PP3PPP/R4RK1&amp;square_size=30&amp;ds_color=(121,146,164)&amp;ls_color=(241,235,226)" /> </a> </div>
```

Comment: You have in excess of 250 rep and have asked 54 questions (as I write this); you should know, by now, to add the relevant ("[MCVE]") code to your question.

Comment: Fixed. Sorry about that.

Comment: And yet there's still no code in your question. Linking to the site with the problem isn't acceptable here, because as soon as the problem is solved the issue is no longer present on your site to illustrate the problem with which you're seeking help; which renders the question nonsensical, at best, and entirely useless at worst. Please: include the relevant minimal code (HTML and CSS) to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Your question is about Lazy load technique.

Check this link:
http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_fadein.html

Comment: I re-read the docmentation and found the solution: <style>
.lazyload,
.lazyloading {
    opacity: 0;
}
.lazyloaded {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 300ms;
}
</style>

Answer (score 0):

since you are using an external third party stylesheet ( and even link to it directly) you should look there by yourself.
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/ color scheme seems to match your tone of orange